# qt5 on android don't record PCM wav files with QAudioRecorder

Tags: android, qt5, pyqt5, qtmultimedia, qaudiorecorder

I wrote code on pyqt5 to record audio files in PCM codec to wav format. And it is fine on PC, but on android it is always write mp4 files with amr codec. How can i fix it?

Here is the code

```
recorder=QAudioRecorder(w)

audioSettings=QAudioEncoderSettings()
audioSettings.setCodec("audio/PCM")
audioSettings.setSampleRate(16000)
recorder.setAudioSettings(audioSettings);

recorder.setContainerFormat("wav");
recorder.setOutputLocation(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/sdcard/test"))
```

(Pyqt5 installed from pip in Pydroid 2 app on android, qt5 from Ministro II app)

Comment: Your device probably doesn't have the necessary codecs, and so falls back to a default. What is the output of `QAudioDeviceInfo().supportedCodecs()`?

Comment: Hmmm. It's really misterious,but supportedCodecs() is ... Empty!!! It is a list with zero length. But, why??? Also, documentation says that "audio/PCM" is available everywhere, so it must be at least 1!

Comment: I run it on PC, and it is empty, as on android. May be,it's a bug in python wrapper....

Comment: Actually, it seems you need to get the list of [availableDevices](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#availableDevices), and then query `supportedCodecs` for each device. However, for me (on linux), this just returns "audio/PCM" for every device. (PS: there is definitely no bug in pyqt or qt. This is purely a matter of system setup).

Comment: I check more accurately, print QAudioDeviceInfo.defaultInputDevice().supportedCodecs() show 'audio/pcm' both on linux and on android. No signs of mp4 and amr codec:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't solve the problem with QAudioRecorder. I find the way to write headerless signed-int 16bit 16khz little endian PCM with QAudioInput:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioInput,QAudioFormat,QAudio
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QPushButton

format=QAudioFormat()
format.setSampleRate(16000);
format.setChannelCount(1);
format.setSampleSize(16);
format.setCodec("audio/pcm")

format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.SignedInt)

audio=QAudioInput(format)

def onBtn():
    if audio.state()==QAudio.StoppedState:
        audio.start(destFile)
        print "started"
    else:
        audio.stop()
        print "stopped"
pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
btnRec = QPushButton('Rec|stop', w)
btnRec.clicked.connect(onBtn)
w.show()
app.exec_()

destFile.close()
```